# manage php session from android webview

Tags: php, android, session, webview

I am developing an android app which has PHP backend. The question is about login process.

I want to login in my native app with 2 EditText(Username,Password). When I post my values to backend service they will send me back a URL for viewing in android web view. But my web page check php sessions and shows 2 different UI according to session state.

If session is null, it always shows login ui. 
So how can I set PHP sessions from web view? It's mandatory to update PHP sessions from mobile app for me.